# Ocaml - Find number of words in a list

Tags: ocaml

From a list example ["dog";"cat";"dog";"cat";"dog"] i have to find the number of time that a word result in this list 
Result -> [("dog",3);("cat",2)]
But i obtain a strange result: [("dog", 1); ("cat", 1); ("dog", 2); ("cat", 2); ("dog", 3)]

My code is this:

```
let rec nuovaParola par l =
 match l with 
 [] -> true
 |(a,_)::z ->if (par=a) then false
             else nuovaParola par (List.tl l);;

let rec contaParole par l =
 let rec contatore par l cont =
  match l with 
   [] -> (par, cont)
   |x::y -> if(par=x) then contatore par y (cont+1)
            else contatore par y cont
 in contatore par l 0;; 

let rec occorrenze l =
 let rec aux l l1=
 match l with 
  [] -> l1
  |x::y -> if (nuovaParola x l1) then aux y l1@[(contaParole x l)]
           else aux y l1
 in aux l [];;`
```

nuovaParola gives me true if the word isn't inside the list else gives me false.

contaParola resturns the tuple with ("word", number);

Occorrenze is the main function. I don't find the problem!
Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create a histogram OCaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442527/create-a-histogram-ocaml)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you have the same problem as the cited earlier StackOverflow page. You're adding a new element to the output for every word you find. This won't work, as you want to have only one element in the output for each unique word.

In essence, you need to update the existing entry in the list rather than adding a new one.

However, lists in OCaml are immutable. You can't actually update a list, you can only create a new one with the desired contents.

Here is a function that updates a list of non-negative ints: it rounds every element up to the next even number.

```
let rec upeven l =
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | h :: t ->
        let h' = if h mod 2 = 1 then h + 1 else h in
        h' :: upeven t
```

The key point is that this function doesn't modify the list `l`, it creates a new list that is modified as desired.

This is similar to your problem, except that you're looking for the element that matches your word, rather than for odd numbers.

As a side comment, using a list to store your counts is not a particularly scalable solution. If your input lists can be large, it would be better to use something with log n complexity, such as a Map. With a list you get linear complexity, so you get n^2 complexity overall. I'm assuming this isn't the main point; i.e., this is a learning exercise.