# Ocaml string histogram

Tags: string, ocaml, histogram

I'm trying to do an Histogram from String in OCaml.
I'm at this state, editing a little this: [create a histogram OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442527/create-a-histogram-ocaml) to use a String input.

How can I see the content of charFreqs, or does it works?

```
module S = String;;
module HT = Hashtbl;;

let histogram s =
    let charFreqs = HT.create 126 in
        S.iter (fun c ->
            let tmp =
                try HT.find charFreqs c
                with Not_found -> 0 in
            HT.replace charFreqs c (tmp+1)
        ) s;;

let str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";;
let charFreqs = histogram str;;
```

> Output: val charFreqs : unit = ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `histogram` function returns the result of S.iter, which is `unit`:

```
val iter : (char -> unit) -> string -> unit
```

Try something like:

```
let histogram s =
    let charFreqs = HT.create 126 in
        S.iter (fun c ->
            let tmp =
                try HT.find charFreqs c
                with Not_found -> 0 in
            HT.replace charFreqs c (tmp+1)
        ) s;
        charFreqs;;
```

Comment: Better:  val charFreqs : (char, int) HT.t = <abstr>

And how can I use it?

Comment: `HT.iter (fun x y -> Printf.printf "%c -> %d\n" x y) charFreqs;;`

Comment: You are officially my Ocaml God \o/

Answer (score 0):

Presented as an alternative: a purely functional approach using [`Map`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Map.html).

```
module Histogram (T : Map.OrderedType) = struct
  module M = Map.Make (T)

  let histogram seq =
    seq 
    |> Seq.fold_left 
         (fun i x -> 
            M.update x 
              (function 
               | None -> Some 1 
               | Some n -> Some (n+1)) i) 
         M.empty
    |> M.bindings
end
```

```
# let open Histogram (Char) in
  "hello" |> String.to_seq |> histogram;;
- : (Char.t * int) list = [('e', 1); ('h', 1); ('l', 2); ('o', 1)]
```